# git - getting a sea of red when committing

Tags: git

I've edited a file in Xcode and saved it.

I've literally changed no more than 2 or 3 lines. However, when I come to checking this code in I have a sea of red in my terminal. I can't check this file in now as my changes are being drowned out. I'm now going to have to work out all the changes I've made, checkout the old file, update the file again and check it in.

Presumably there's been a line ending change. I've experimented setting `autocrlf` in the past but found it's just caused more trouble.

I'm the only person committing to this repo. Is there any way I can make the entire code base consistent so that I can commit without distractions like this.

Comment: Git, by default, tracks permissions too. Can you check, if the sea of red is because of changed modes?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config –-global core.safecrlf true
```

On Linux:

```
git config –-global core.autocrlf input
git config –-global core.safecrlf true
```

Documentation:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreautocrlf
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresafecrlf

Comment: @Snow Crash: It's UX-based, so use Linux settings

Comment: @SnowCrash
Hope this helps 
https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-mac